# Managing module library dependencies with composer

Tags: 8, installation, composer

I've found [Dependencies in a custom module with drupal-composer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198138/dependencies-in-a-custom-module-with-drupal-composer), [How can I include a third party library in my custom module without using Composer Manager](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188519/how-can-i-include-a-third-party-library-in-my-custom-module-without-using-compos) and [How to manage contrib modules composer dependencies on drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86109/how-to-manage-contrib-modules-composer-dependencies-on-drupal-8) which are releated to my question, but no longer seem to apply since Drupal 8.1 and the deprecation of [Composer manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager).

Also popular guides such as [The definitive introduction to D8 and Composer](https://bojanz.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/d8-composer-definitive-intro/) appear to no longer apply as they also mention composer manager.

The other solution opposed to composer manager, alter the core composer.json file feels like too much core hacking and would probably break with every Drush update of Drupal core(?).

More specifically, I am attempting to update [Views vCards](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_vcards) from Drupal 7 to 8. I have created my composer.json file as follows:

```
{
  "name": "drupal/views_vcards",
  "description": "Allows creation of vCards using the fields provided by the Views module.",
  "type": "drupal-module",
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "homepage": "https://drupal.org/project/views_vcards",
  "require": {
    "maennchen/zipstream-php": "0.3.*"
  }
}
```

But if I put a composer.json file in my module folder, how do I make Drupal aware that that file is there, and how do I make sure the required `zipstream-php` library is downloaded?

Simply running `composer update` from the Drupal root does update a lot of Drupal dependencies, but it does not include the composer.json files that are in the modules folders. I also don't assume I should be calling `composer install` from inside all modules with dependencies.

How do I make Drupal aware of a module's dependency without using composer manager and/or hacking core?

UPDATE:

The [composer merge plugin used by core](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) appears to have support a wildcard path:

```
{
    "require": {
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master"
    },
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "composer.local.json",
                "extensions/*/composer.json" // < ---- THIS LINE
            ],
            "require": [
                "submodule/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-dev": true,
            "merge-extra": false
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't core merge `modules/*/composer.json`, that would solve everything right?

Update 2:

THe reasoning for not supporting this is covered in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2609568) (which also has been quiet for some time now).

Comment: Editing the main composer file is the corrected way.

Comment: If you let composer manage all of your dependencies (core included) then your issue will disappear. See https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core

Comment: Here is an example composer file I wrote for another question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187097/40011

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Eyal. So managing all contrib modules via the `composer.json` file is the new recommended way and drush for downloading and installing modules is getting replaced? Obviously will composer automatically resolve nested dependencies and indeed also download my dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### New method using drupal-scaffold for greatest flexibility

**For Drupal 8.4.0 and greater using drush >9.0.0**, drush make is deprecated and you should use a full-composer work flow as detailed in the drupal.org documentation links below. Those links do recommend using a composer project, but this may not work for everyone's web server setup. The following is step-by-step how to setup composer.json *manually* for detail explanation. The instructions regarding adding modules manually can still be done.

```
# Initialize composer. Stability alpha is important for custom modules that may be source managed outside of packagist or drupal.org
composer init --name myvendor/mysite --stability=alpha --license=GPLv2
composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8
composer config discard-changes true
```

Then you need to add to composer.json *manually* the following based on your preferences because there is no way to do so automatically with composer as-is. These will configure drupal-scaffold to install your modules *where you want them* (as opposed to in vendor/ or a directory chosen by some other developer). Change 'webroot' to 'www' or 'public' or what your host is.

```
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "webroot/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "webroot/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "webroot/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "webroot/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "webroot/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"],
            "webroot/profiles/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "webroot/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"]
        },
        "patches": {}
    },
    "scripts": {
        "drupal-scaffold": "DrupalComposer\\DrupalScaffold\\Plugin::scaffold"
    }
```

Now you can install some dependencies. Note that composer must be able to use scripts and plugins for this to work.

```
composer require composer/installers:^1.4.0 drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold:^2.3.0 cweagans/composer-patches:^1.6.2
```

Run the drupal-scaffold script once (or on your build server as needed):

```
composer drupal-scaffold
```

Drupal core, modules, themes, etc... can be installed as per the instructions below without the drupal-merge-plugin.

```
composer require drupal/core:~8.5.1 drupal/views_vcards
```

#### Older method using drupal-merge-plugin or working with core directly

For Drupal 8.1.0 and greater, you can use composer to require Drupal modules directly. The documentation around [Using Composer in a Drupal project](https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989) and [Using Composer to install Drupal packages through Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-packages-through-drupalorg) has been updated to take advantage of drupal.org's packagist. I find it works well already in a deployment scenario.

```
composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8
composer require drupal/views_vcards
```

For development, I think that manually adding in the dependency with `composer require` works fine. The merge approach works too with the drupal-merge-plugin and I use this for my drush make work flow.

```
composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8
composer require mile23/drupal-merge-plugin
composer update
```

#### Update 2016.06.22

I ran into an issue using drush make, which added the traditional Drupal version tags and drupal.org packagist URLs using semver. To that end, I needed to switch to using the stabler packagist at https://packagist.drupal-composer.org, which still supports the traditional Drupal version tags.

Also note that the build server or machine [requires an exorbitant amount of memory to do a composer update](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898) (or require), which is necessary in all scenarios where running composer update on a similar development machine is not possible in your build process.

#### Update 2016.09.23

- Added link to [Using Composer to install Drupal packages through Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-packages-through-drupalorg).
- Added onto the development section about how I use it with drush make.

#### Update 2018.03.30

- Noticed an up vote. This is fairly old so decided to clarify about more recent development and setting up your site directly with composer since drush make has been (sadly) deprecated for a while.

Comment: I am still very used to using drush to download and install modules, but that will be entirely replaced with composer?

Comment: That's how drupalci is doing it now, but before that, you could use the merge plugin directly. The patch I wrote for drupalci initially was https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2597778-composer-contrib-18.patch. This was committed, but now no longer in the code base as it's simplified to use the packagist and do everything from composer iirc. I also do the following with TravisCI: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/xero/tree/.travis.yml#n40. It will depend on your work flow.

Comment: Maybe worth adding a blurb about Asset Packagist here for 3rd-party libraries with Composer. This methodology is being adopted by a number of Drupal distros and several contrib modules are now using it as well.  I've just contributed some documentation to officialize this solution https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#third-party-libraries and https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/managing-dependencies-for-a-contributed-project#third-party-libraries